# When using a function as a first-class value in Typescript, is there a way to pass Generic bindings?

Tags: typescript, function, generics, first-class-functions

I am attempting to wrap typescript functions, returning new functions that add extra behaviour. For example, in the minimal repro below, (see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=3#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%20oTTVOp5RSiCgkh5CBUIgAAxjEcZLw%20cAAJN7w2ymQBfAvsHZptMZjDSgGC%20CEcjeciXNQYUO01lxmhNv0tts0LO2XP5gsC-LwaFVj5dhsTlMt-2fCyd5fN1N14Qn3bG9x4XKhIjkOgYdShABGQ3%20T-vj5fUHYybTAa%205BwAA1HAT47GewgXtqlTAHk5CIIUABqXBEAAbuQeTqMADCIf8oT0A%20z5DD%20k7-vuGDAN48xjL0yFEEQ65ZqhwD-B8ABWwBuImv47gopiWNo9wQOoMD0YmjF5MxaEYVh7B4eOk51uwp7CMI07wGaeIAMqPohMk5FSZq4EQ17Kbs6kKjieIACKwfBemYaghBGUOMFwYgZnCMGzhQR4oB3GAoJEJwPHTBZ15Ur2-YaVZHo6aEDlYTQRAAMy-AALGZrZSvAbnwR6iVOYwfYDppHq2e5hVEAARFcsG5tV-wAIwAAxtWZdZwEAA)) the function after wrapping always returns a Promise and its arguments and return value are console-logged.

However, I have found that if the original function has any Generic typing, I don't know how to bind that Generic type so it is available on the wrapped function even if it is well-known in the calling scope.

The problem is demonstrated by `const delayedValue` in the below script. Typescript seems to  believe this can only be unknown.

Is there any way for e.g. `wrappedDelay` to be defined such that the generic `V` parameter can make it through and hence inform what return type we can expect from the `wrappedDelay` function.

```
export type AnyFn = (...args: any[]) => any;

/** If sync function - ReturnType. If async function - unwrap Promise of ReturnType */
export type Result<Fn extends AnyFn> = Fn extends () => Promise<infer Promised>
  ? Promised
  : ReturnType<Fn>;

/** Async function with same params and return as Fn, regardless if Fn is sync or async  */
export type WrappedFn<Fn extends AnyFn> = (...parameters:Parameters<Fn>) => Promise<Result<Fn>>

/** Construct wrapped function from function reference */
function wrapFn<Fn extends AnyFn>(fn:Fn) : WrappedFn<Fn>{
    return async (...parameters:Parameters<Fn>) => {
        console.log(`Parameters are ${parameters}`);
        const result = await fn(...parameters);
        console.log(`Result is ${result}`);
        return result;
    }
}

function sum(a:number, b:number){
    return a + b;
}

function delay<V>(value: V, ms:number){
    return new Promise<V>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms)
    })
}

const wrappedSum = wrapFn(sum)

const wrappedDelay = wrapFn(delay)

async function example() {
    const sum = await wrappedSum(3,4)
    const delayedValue = await wrappedDelay("hello", 1000)
}
```

Comment: *Thank you* for the [mcve] playground link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not have direct support for "higher kinded types" of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), so there's no *general* way to manipulate generic functions programmatically in such a way as express a *purely type-level* transformation of the function type `F` to function type `G` where any generic type parameters on `F` get transferred to `G`.

Luckily, since TypeScript 3.4, there *is* support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) where you can get behavior like this for *particular* functions at the *value-level*, such as `wrapFn()` acting on input functions which are generic.  So if `f` is a function of type `F`, and `const g = wrapFn(f)`, it is possible to write `wrapFn()` so that `g` is of type `G`, where any generic type parameters of `F` have been transferred to `G`.

You can read [microsoft/TypeScript#30215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) for how this higher order type inference works and the  rules you need to follow to get this behavior.  In particular, this feature expects that you will have separate type parameters for the function arguments (e.g., `A extends any[]`) and for the return (e.g., `R`).  It does *not* work with a generic function type like `F extends (...args: any[])=>any` where you use [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) utility types like `Parameters<F>` or `ReturnType<F>` to extract argument types or return types from it.

So, if you change `WrappedFn` and `wrapFn` to the folllowing:

```
type WrappedFn<A extends any[], R> = (...parameters: A) => Promise<R>

function wrapFn<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => R): WrappedFn<A, R> {
    return async (...parameters: A) => {
        console.log(`Parameters are ${parameters}`);
        const result = await fn(...parameters);
        console.log(`Result is ${result}`);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then things behave as you expect, at least for the example code in your question:

```
const wrappedDelayValue = wrapFn(delay);
// const wrappedDelayValue: <V>(value: V, ms: number) => Promise<Promise<V>>

const delayedValue = await wrappedDelayValue("hello", 1000);
// const delayedValue: string    
console.log(delayedValue.toUpperCase()) // no compiler error now
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAYnKBeKAKAdDghgJwHMBnALilwQG0BdASjQD4KEBuAWACgvRIoAlCMQCuAG2AAeZFAgAPYBDgATYrATJm6aXIXLVGBqmYAFfAHsAtgEtiECVbgAzCPiinLNiEsZcofqAD8bubWtkq+-uSCwML4cAAq4HYaHNycvNAA6vi4YJBKyBIwMvKKKiwgtAA0ApqYOFhgBLgWEAr4ZLCGJiGeEvw+aY7CcADGwFZmKADuOWCFxTplqpSVNDUDGI5w5Nh4RJ0w3QJ05Nm5+QsbzADeEX74bbEouMQgY-U4TTmt7YfHd04-mBUFGU2IZlEECwojMhAwAANjM1fi4Vo8oAASG7fFptNEAXwRdFSIP8YLgxGAUEeInEaAo01wVmp2z2jRR+I6JPuIIpEKhMLhiMEdOpNixN1pYmARJ5QLJNKecSVYtJ-gJXE1QxG40mKBEFgwuHIcGEFgARi4ahbTearfgGIDgY8YircFAANRQC2pbVcYZjCZTKBKCCiXAgCQANUYGAAbrhRMIIORozULJ0zZaXE7ea7nlA4BBpsEPLYY3GMLTIfGIDVHgArCDjAG84G2YDxKytMzCYAYAxMVW1iAJpMpugZ4h0XkE2ecf2cfnU2YXLwAZXN0YnQgZa-mcAwhoXXBXUAP+QAIuHIzvk9B0AfkBgwxGQPKAPSf0Hg1dza9bxAe8U3IStxwfNNpztHNHWHdxQjsBC+ljQYuFed5RigQM9RDOQWjAKEh2dck-ygQ0GVwJkWQvADN23XdiAwABmGoABYF2Bc830jLwQMfRlmX-dclBvd9+IwAAiAALcNYUkmoAEYAAZVPlYFv1-SlqR4kA+N3cgqXwBxCGBXl+UhaFYXhXT9IfLBgDMABVPIXAAYVeMc6AYTS4DMX8LDAKwoVcFxzFcPzpi1LguHwwKiJJIA)

Comment: Brilliant! I rely on @jcalz fixing all my hard cases! Given the Promise identity (Promise<Promise<A>> is Promise<A>) I think the fix you provide will just work for my case. It's a curiosity that adding back the intermediate type `type Awaited<T> = T extends Promise<infer Promised> ? Promised : T;` and using it like `type WrappedFn<A extends any[], R> = (...parameters: A) => Promise<Awaited<R>>` wasn't able to be accepted by Typescript, in spite of the Promise identity. With luck I don't need that intermediate in my real-world case (wrapping both non-await and await code with yield).

Comment: And just to clarify, any attempt to use a function type as a 'reference' for its arguments and return are therefore flawed. In my case (yielding future sync/async invocations) `export type Invocation<A extends any[], R> = [(...args:A) => R, A]` will always have to have the two generic arguments and can never be composed from a reference to the function type Fn itself.

Comment: @cefn I think you can get rid of the `Promise<Promise<..>>` types by adding `| Promise<R>`, to `fn`'s return type in `wrapFn`, i.e. `(fn: (...args: A) => R | Promise<R>)`.

Comment: Thanks Oblosys. I was avoiding that route since it seemed to be opening up two possible code paths meaning I would have types of both `Promise<string>` and `string` showing up in returned values, and when I know for sure I only want `string`. My real-world case is more-or-less equivalent to the call() effect in redux-saga. I want the yield to always give back a string if the function called was () => string but also always a string if the function called was () => Promise<string> ( https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#callfn-args ). The infer avoids the need for predicates or guards.